# Size of partition on Virtual Box guest system

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage

I have Kubuntu as a host system and ubuntu as a guest system on Virtual Box. Virtual hard drive was created with flag "Dynamically allocated storage" so I assumed that size of the storage should grow with system requirements.

Now I'm checking on my virtual system:

```
$df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        11G  6.5G  3.7G  65% /
```

But virtual box indicates more than 93% :
[image: Virtual box - disk information]

and that is real size of virtual disk on host system

```
$ls -s Ubuntu.vdi -h 
12G Ubuntu.vdi
```

Two questions:

1. why?
2. how to reduce actual size to 65%?

Thanks!

Comment: See [How to compact VirtualBox's VDI file size?](http://superuser.com/q/529149)

Comment: @JonasCz - thank you! It works with some modifications! Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @JonasC, I was able to reduce it quite easily.

First you need R.I.P.-linux or any other rescue system with zerofree util. 
Boot this rescue system and run

```
zerofree -v /dev/sda1
```

Then stop virtual machine and run on host

```
vboxmanage modifyhd /path/to/thedisk.vdi --compact
```

Result is obvious:

```
$ls -sh Ubuntu.vdi 
12G Ubuntu.vdi

$ vboxmanage modifyhd Ubuntu.vdi  --compact
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

$ ls -sh Ubuntu.vdi 
8.2G Ubuntu.vdi
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is is that VDI system requires space.
More on:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8046

Why would you want to reduce the the actual size?
The actual size is not the "actual" size of the .vdi file, but the actual size of the virtual disk usable inside Virtual Machine.
try opening the terminal and type:
ls -R ~/VirtualBox VMs
you'll see that the actual size is smaller.
Or perhaps, you have hidden data.

Comment: I don't think you are right Virtual Box indicates actual size of virtual disk on host system: ` ls -s Ubuntu.vdi -h 
12G Ubuntu.vdi`

Comment: If you're absolutelly sure, you could try making another smaller .vdi and attaching it to the VB system. Then you could do: sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 after creating the filesystem

Comment: the drive dinamically allocated has a variable size, but perhaps you had more data and data don't delete merelly with rm and filesystem rezises

Comment: Well @Cloacker there is a golden rule in technical forums - suggest something that you are sure! dd will create 'byte copy' of disk byte-by-byte a whole volume. **So new volume will have the same size as the old one.** It is very bad Answer!

Comment: ok, dd only copies equals. if the size is different he'll get an error on the end. I was assuming that he just resized the original partition to the size he wanted (lets say 6.6GB for example). Then the new .vdi would be 6.6GB. I thought It was too obvious. Sorry.

Comment: what to do. briefly: 1) resize partition to 6.6GB 2) plug the new .vdi with any virtual size you want(bigger). 3) make a partition on the new vdi that has the same size of the first. 4) dd it 5) now you can resize it to lets say 20 gb, and it'll only occupy 6.6 gb. It has to be a .vdi supported filesystem.

Comment: I don't need to resize my partition! I need reduce actual size of virtual disk on host system! Please read question carefully. The correct answer below and it works **for sure**!

Comment: man, I just said to reduce the sda1 on virtual host, not the .vdi. You .vdi continues to have 1.7 of garbage data. This already happened with me. I had a small .vdi and after putting some data on it, I was unable to get the original size of the .vdi. So I did this workaround.